# jQuery parent and child divs activating different actions

Tags: jquery, html, event-propagation

I have an element that contains many components within it. Lets call this element box. Now inside the box I have many different elements, pictures, text and buttons.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/roman_khrystynych/FSCRH/

HTML:

```
    <div id="container">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="button">Click</div>    
        </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
    $('#container').on("click", ".box", function(){
        alert('box'); //only when anything in box except button
    });

    $('#container').on("click", ".button", function(){
        alert('button'); //only when button clicked
    });
```

Issue is that when clicking button the box element also activates its actions. Essentially I want it to be an exception that if I click on the button the regular box actions do no occur but instead the button actions occur. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're talking about is event bubbling.  When you click on a child element, it also triggers a click event on every single parent all the way up to the top of the DOM tree.

stopPropagation() will cancel bubbling up the dom tree

Try this:

```
  $('#container').on("click", ".button", function(e){
        e.stopPropagation()
        alert('button'); //only when button clicked
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

jquery has a function for it. http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

`stopPropagation();`

it stops the click event from bubbling.

http://jsfiddle.net/honk1/FSCRH/1/